# Cannot connect to MS Access using UCanAccess

Tags: jdbc, odbc, jdbc-odbc, dbvisualizer

I'm using DbVisualizer Free 11.0 [Build #3077]

OS: Windows 10

OS Arch: amd64

Java Version: 1.8.0_242

Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Trying to create UCanAccess driver using the following theme:

http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG92/JDBC-ODBC+Bridge+Driver+Alternatives

But the current versions are different and now my Driver Manager looks like this:
[image]

Seems to be, it's ok, but when I try to connect I see the following message:

[image]

Where am I wrong? Quotes or spaces in Path? Jars versions? Jars should be placed in defined place?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: According to your screenshot, you have provided a Log4J 1.2 JAR file, which includes a class called `org.apache.log4j.Logger`. However, the error messages suggests you need to include the Log4j 2.x API JAR, which includes `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`. You can download that JAR from Maven [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.13.3/log4j-api-2.13.3.jar). Perhaps the instructions on the DbVisualizer site are out of date.

Comment: Minor point: Be consistent with your path separators in your database URL, by using forward slashes `/` throughout. You have a mix of forward and backslashes. This example works fine for me on Windows: `jdbc:ucanaccess://e:/data files/database1.accdb`.

Comment: @andrewjames thanks a lot!
It works fine with slashes and Log4J Jar file.